# In python is there a way to make a function/class that behaves like a function and a context manager?

Tags: python, function, oop, python-decorators, contextmanager

In python is there a way to make a function/class that behaves like a function and a context manager?

**Note**: that I need the function/class to return an object that doesn't have a `__exit__` method and I cant change that object (that's why I am wrapping it).

so just making a class with `__enter__` and `__exit__` won't work because I need it to also behave like a function.

I have tried the `contextmanager` decorator:

```
@contextmanager
def my_context_man(my_str):
    my_str = 'begging ' + my_str
    yield my_str+' after func'
    print('end')
```

And it worked perfectly within the context manger, but not as a function:

```
a = 'middle'
old_a = my_context_man(a)
print('old_a', old_a)

with my_context_man(a) as new_a:
    print('new_a', new_a)
```

the output:

```
old_a <contextlib._GeneratorContextManager object at 0x0000000004F832E8>
new_a begging middle after func
end
```

while the desired output will be:

```
old_a begging middle after func
new_a begging middle after func
end
```

**edit**:
The specific problem that i am having is with the `psycopg2` module.
I want to use a different context manager. and it returns a connection object.

```
def connect(dsn=None, connection_factory=None, cursor_factory=None, **kwargs):
    *the connection code*    
    return conn
```

I am trying to change it so that people will be able to use it with my context manager but in a way that will not break code.
I **cannot** change the conn object

Comment: You have a bit of [XY](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) going on here.  It is definitively possible for a Class to be a context manager and a function.  But what you are trying to achieve with that is not clear.

Comment: edited the question, I hope its clearer now. @StephenRauch

Comment: Constructing the context manager will give you a context manager.  You can then call that context manager, or if you simply want it to return a string, that can also be done.  But you have not yet described what you are actually trying to do.  Please read the XY link from my earlier comment.

Comment: It's not clear you know what a context manager is or what it is for.

Comment: I edited again. Is that clear enough? @StephenRauch

Comment: `connection` objects have usable as context managers since [version 2.5](http://initd.org/psycopg/articles/2013/04/07/psycopg-25-released/), released nearly 5 years ago.

Answer (score 0):

Your `__new__` method isn't returning an instance of `my_context_man`, but an instance of `str`, and `str` doesn't have an `__enter__` method. It's the return value of `__enter__` that gets bound to the name after `as` in the `with` statement. You want

```
class my_context_man:
    def __init__(self, my_str):
        self.msg = my_str
        print("beginning " + my_str)

    def __enter__(self):
        return self.msg

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        print('end')
```

Comment: How does this solve the *I want to call it like a function*?

Comment: you (@StephenRauch) are right, but that`s a bit besides the point.

Comment: I don't even know what that means. A context manager is just an object that has `__enter__` and `__exit__` methods that obey the context-manager protocol.

Comment: Yeah, which is why I did not answer the question initially.  OP is having some challenges with some more advanced concepts.  Definitely some XY going on.

Comment: Sure, but I figure seeing how a context manager should be defined from scratch, rather than with `contextlib.contextmanager`, would be a good start.

Comment: I edited again. Is that clear enough? @chepner
and i understand what are context managers for and how they are created.